# Almost periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, number-theory, diophantine-approximation, almost-periodic-functions

I am trying to do this problem but could figure it out.

> Show that $f(x) = \cos 2\pi x +\cos 2\pi \sqrt{2} x$ is almost-periodic by showing directly
>   that given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $M$ such that at least one of any $M$ consecutive integers lies within $\varepsilon$ from an integral multiple of $2\pi$.

The definition of almost periodic is based on the notion of relatively dense set.

> A set $\mathcal{F}\subset \mathbb{R}$ is relatively dense in
>   $\mathbb{R}$ if there exists a constant $L>0$ such that $(x,x+L)\cap F
>  \neq \emptyset$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then a bounded uniformly
>   continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
>   "almost periodic" iff for any $\varepsilon >0$, the set  $$
>  \mathcal{F}_\varepsilon = \left\lbrace h\in \mathbb{R}:\sup_{x\in
> > \mathbb{R}} \left|f(x+h) - f(x)\right| <\varepsilon \right\rbrace$$ is
>   relatively dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt is based on the observation that for $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ then 
$$ f(x+m) - f(x) = \cos(2\pi \sqrt{2} x + 2\pi \sqrt{2}m) - \cos (2\pi \sqrt{2} x)$$
and thus
$$ |f(x+m) - f(x)| \leq 2\pi\Big( \inf_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \left|m\sqrt{2}+n\right| \Big)$$
We know that the set $\left\lbrace m\sqrt{2} + n: m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\rbrace$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (by a simple Pidgeonhole argument). Thus the problem will be soved if we can show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, the set 
$$ \mathcal{F} = \left\lbrace m\in  \mathbb{Z}: \;\text{there exists}\;n\in \mathbb{Z}\;\text{such that}\quad |m\sqrt{2}+n| < \varepsilon\right\rbrace$$
is "relatively dense" in $\mathbb{R}$, where relatively dense means there exists a constant $M_\varepsilon>0$ such that any interval $(x,x+M_\varepsilon)$ contains at least one element of $\mathcal{F}$.

This somehow relates to the problem of approximation $\sqrt{2}$ by rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ but we want the set of $q$ is relatively dense. One well-known result is the Dirichlet approximation theorem, which states that  showing that any real number has a sequence of good rational approximations: in fact an immediate consequence is that for a given irrational $\alpha$, the inequality
$$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{q^2}$$
is satisfied by infinitely many integers $p$ and $q$. But the problem how to control the distance between two consecutive denumerators still cannot be solved.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: What's your definition of an almost periodic function ?

Comment: I presume that the definition is given in the second paragraph.  I've blockquoted it to make it pop a bit more.

Comment: I added the definition of almost periodic functions.

Comment: What does mean " lies within $\epsilon$ from an integral multiple of $2\pi$, please? (my English is deficient)

Comment: Your "We know that the set $\{m\sqrt2+n:\space m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in$\mathbb R$" deserves an explanation for the beginners. In fact, it is known that for all irrational $\alpha$ the fractional parts of $n\alpha$ when $n$ runs the integers form a dense set on $[0,1]$. What you say about it is easily deduced from this.

Comment: @Piquito: What does mean " lies within ϵ
from an integral multiple of 2π, please? (my English is deficient): This is the definition I added after that.

Comment: Thanks you. I understand now.

Comment: is $f(x) = \cos(x * 2 \pi) + \cos(x * 2 \pi *\sqrt{2})$ ?

Comment: @Ahmad: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So since $\cos(2 \pi x)=1$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $-1 \leq \cos \alpha \leq 1$ so the only integral multiple of $2 \pi$ in the function interval is $0$, so you are asking that  in consecutive $M$ integers there is at least one of them such that $1+\cos(2\pi x \sqrt{2} )\leq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ very small.

Comment: @Ahmad: I think you misunderstood the problem. We subtract f(x+m) - f(x) and want the difference is smaller than $\varepsilon$